# Heroku refuses connection to postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql, ssl, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Flask app based on PostgreSQL on Heroku, but I when I try to create the table with `db.create_all()` I keep getting this error:

```
(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect t
rver: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here is how my code looks like:

```
app=Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='postgres://kfgriimpfjecsv:Bk1*****G@localhost:5432/dd71doth8gopgh'
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug=True
    app.run()
```

I am using Heroku Toolbelt to communicate with Heroku servers. Also, when I try this:

```
psql -p 5432 -h localhost
```

I get almost the same error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I also tried `ec2-23-21-215-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com` instead of `localhost` in the URI, but got the same error.

And [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxr1tgeivpyk0tt/traceback.txt?dl=0) is the complete traceback that I get when I run db.create_all():

Any idea why the connection is being refused and how to solve this?

Comment: if you get it from the cli as well, then obviously either pg isn't running, it's not listening for tcp, or it's not listening on that ip:port combo.

Comment: If it is linux you should check for the service. It does not look like the two errors will be the same, just because psql cannot give psycopg errors, a detailed error log from cli will be more helpful.
Other alternatives are check the status of the service, firewall, and the port itself.
Proper permissions to the database as well.

Comment: I edited the question by adding the traceback, but not sure how to check for the service. I'll have to dig a bit on how to do that.

Comment: See the SSL section (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku#ssl) of the Heroku docs.

Comment: @c0dem4gnetic that's a clue, but I thought I was running that from inside the server. My app files have been deployed and I am typing that code inside a bash which I opened with `heroku run bash` form my computer terminal. Doesn't the server consider the commands I give to the bash as an inside connection? I thought "outside" meant if I run a script locally and point to a remote database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had to append a sslmode parameter to the database URI, so changing the second line to the following solved the problem:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= "postgresql+psycopg2://kfgriimpfjecsv:Bk1*******G@ec2-23-21-215-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dd71doth8gopgh?sslmode=require"
```

Comment: Tip: use `os.environ['DATABASE_URL']` to get the connection parameters. 1) It's Heroku's recommended solution (read http://12factor.net for background) 2) you shouldn't put credentials in your code and 3) doing so will let you rotate credentials (via `heroku pg:credentials --reset`) without redeploying code.